# Qt / Windows: crash when connecting a signal and slot in the constructor of a globally scoped object

Tags: c++, windows, qt

The following program will crash when I compile and run it in Qt Creator on Windows:

TestObject.h:

```
#include <QObject>

class TestObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestObject(QObject *parent = nullptr);
signals:
    void signal();
public slots:
    void slot();
};
```

TestObject.cpp:

```
#include "TestObject.h"

TestObject::TestObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(this, &TestObject::signal, this, &TestObject::slot);
}

void TestObject::slot() {}

TestObject global;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    TestObject local;
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove either the call to `connect` in TestObject's constructor or `TestObject globalVar;` then there's no crash. Something about calling `connect` in the constructor of a globally scoped  is going wrong. The locally scoped variable in `main()` doesn't cause any issues.

I've tried compiling against Qt 5.9.9, 5.11.2, and 5.14.2, and they all have the same crash.

If I compile the same program on macOS, there's no crash.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or some way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy)...

> In general, creating QObjects before the QApplication is not supported
>   and can lead to weird crashes on exit, depending on the platform. This
>   means static instances of QObject are also not supported. A properly
>   structured single or multi-threaded application should make the
>   QApplication be the first created, and last destroyed QObject.

So what you have is currently not supported.